# Wrapping lines with leading speechmark in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext, word-wrap

When using the „Wrap paragraph at XX characters“ AND the praragraph starts with leading speech marks, these will be set in front of every line in this paragraph.

How to reproduce:

- write a text (or generate one at lipsum.com) with on or more paragraphs.
- set the first word (or words) in speechmarks: "Lorem ipsum" dolor...
- mark this paragraph
- select Edit >> Wrap >> Wrap paragraph at 70 characters

You'll get something like

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
"scelerisque sagittis est, ac consectetur lorem mattis tincidunt.
"Vestibulum sit amet lobortis odio, vel sollicitudin enim. Vivamus
"imperdiet tortor eu est malesuada condimentum. Suspendisse et posuere
"urna. Vivamus consequat sapien id vestibulum auctor. Vivamus suscipit
...
```

Can I somehow change this behaviour in the user settings or do I have to treat this as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you'll have make a small edit to `paragraph.py` in the `Packages/Default` folder. How you do this depends on the version of Sublime you're using. If you're using ST2, simply select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open the `Packages` folder in your operating system's file explorer. Go to the `Default` folder, and open `paragraph.py` in Sublime.

If you're using ST3, the process is slightly more complicated, as most packages are stored in zipped `.sublime-package` files. Install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) if you haven't already, then install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. In the Command Palette, select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`, select `Default`, then select `paragraph.py`.

Once you have `paragraph.py` open, scroll down to line 188:

```py
prefix = self.extract_prefix(s)
```

Change it to:

```py
prefix = None # self.extract_prefix(s)
```

and save the file. Now, this text (with a single quote at the beginning):

[image: unwrapped]

becomes:

[image: wrapped]